# How to save high score in Android game

Tags: java, android

I'm making a simple memory game in Android studio. The game contains 2 activities (MainActivity, GameActivity) I need to save the high score from the GameActivity and show it in the MainActivity. I've already attempted using SharedPreferences but the high score remains 0 in the MainActivity.
Here is the code i have in the GameActivity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
String dataName = "MyData";
String intName = "MyInt";
int defaultInt = 0;
int hiScore;

prefs = getSharedPreferences(dataName,MODE_PRIVATE);
editor = prefs.edit();
hiScore = prefs.getInt(intName, defaultInt);
editor.putInt(intName, hiScore);
editor.commit();
```

the code in the MainActivity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
String dataName = "MyData";
String intName = "MyString";
int defaultInt = 0;
public static int hiScore;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences(dataName,MODE_PRIVATE);
    hiScore = prefs.getInt(intName, defaultInt);
    TextView textHiScore =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textHiScore);
    textHiScore.setText("Hi: "+ hiScore);
}
```

Comment: consider using `public static final String` constants to keep your keys consistent across all activities

Comment: Thanks, i will remember that.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving `hiScore` as "MyInt" and trying to retrieve it as "MyString"

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to initialize the hiScore
In the GameActivity:

```
hiScore = prefs.getInt(intName, defaultInt);
editor.putInt(intName, hiScore);
```

you just read the value from the prefs, Did not initialize hiScore, so hiScore value is defaultInt

And in the MainActivity:

```
String intName = "MyString";
hiScore = prefs.getInt(intName, defaultInt);
```

prefs not contain key eqauls "MyString" value, so hiScore value is defaultInt

Answer (score 0):

in the GameActivity

```
String intName = "MyInt";
```

the code in the MainActivity:

```
String intName = "MyString";  // change it to "MyInt"
```

keep same argument to `intName` in both activities.

Comment: Thanks, its now working correctly. I didn't know that the key should have the same name.

Comment: Good. You can keep your constants as a static final variable in a separate class file to use in everywhere.